What do I do if I think an entire site is in the wrong?
To get in front of it, there is no Stack Exchange site that I'm vaguing here, and I recognize that the answer is, to zeroth-order, "deal with it, don't visit that site".
But for instance, the creation of the GenAI site was received negatively with a lot of people questioning whether it was a suitable topic for Stack Exchange, whether there was too much overlap with other sites, etc.
Now, I haven't been back to GenAI much and my impression is that it's, like, fine. Not useful to me, but useful enough to some people. But suppose it isn't, and suppose that I as a person strongly feel that it needs fundamental changes.

"User Story"
Suppose that I have a concern about a particular site like (ALL OF THE FOLLOWING ARE FALSE):

The posts there are all subjective and unanswerable!
The comment section looks like a Facebook wall! Stop wishing each other happy birthday!
The mods aren't doing anything, or are encouraging breaking Stack Exchange rules!
The users have formed factions and are starting an eternal flamewar!
The subject is stupid and unsuited for Stack Exchange!

I've raised my very reasonable opinions in the site's Meta, only to be downvoted by the users and mods because "they like it this way". But the issue is, since this place is a pigsty, the only users who will participate in meta don't understand what makes a proper Q&A site. Any good users have been pushed out just like me, and the remaining populace elects moderators who reflect their bad values. If there was order around here, then maybe the silent majority of good users would come back and the site could actually be good again!
I feel that I need some admin to step in and deliver justice, old-internet style, with a banhammer, and mass post deletions. Preferably they should just delete the entire site and obliterate the backups and –

OK, obviously that's unreasonable. I can't say "I disagree with the elected mods and community, so I deserve to get put in charge". But still, I do think that sometimes one might think that site consensus should be put in balance with network-wide concerns.

Something about a site's behaviour is negatively impacting the "Hot Network Questions" sidebar tab or the experience of finding it in search results.
A decision with majority support is unfairly negatively impacting a minority of users.
A decision with majority support violates Stack Exchange network policy.
I believe that a site should be deleted or changed in scope, or the site has decided to change its scope in a way I disagree with.

I could contact SE, but then it's not an open discussion, and there's no evidence that other people are feeling the same way that I am. I could ask here, but it's a question about one site, even though it may have broader impacts.

Help center: Questions that belong elsewhere include... Meta questions that relate to only one site. Ask these on the child meta of the site they relate to (other than English questions about International sites).

(Which is good, since we don't want meta.SE to become the appeals court for every site's drama.)
Obviously, the first thing I should do in this situation is realize that not every site on the internet needs to be tailored towards me. But if I still feel that the broader network needs to have a voice, how should I approach this?
Related:

What recourse do I have if I believe a moderator has abused their privileges?
Please stop using SoftwareEngineering.SE as your toilet bowl
How do we make changes to a site's scope?


(To reiterate, there's no site that this is about, I just went looking for the answer and didn't see any question like this.)

Well, if the sites really isn't following any of the network rules, has no interest in doing so, and the rest of the network has no interest in changing their rules, then maybe they should split off

@Starship I don't believe there's a way for doing that, is there? SE (company) would, of course, like to keep people on their site, and I would be... surprised if they went along with "we're moving to  and archiving the site! Click here to be redirected!" --- Regardless, the situation I'm talking about here isn't that the majority of users of a site feel restricted and want to leave--in the hypothetical, the majority of site users like being a SE site. If anything, it's kinda the opposite, I guess. (A minority of users wants the network to step in and restrict the site's consensus.)

What’s the point in such a purely hypothetical worst case scenario? One could imagine countless variations, does every outlandish hypothetical scenario need a way of fixing it?

@MisterMiyagi The WMF has had "rogue communities" before like the Croatian Wikipedia

@MisterMiyagi I guess... the "user story" is assembled from bits and pieces of a few times I've felt like I was clearly in the right despite a site's consensus. While I think "site has gone rogue" is rare, "somebody disagrees with a site and feels that they're right and obviously justified and everybody else is wrong" is, I suspect, not particularly rare.

(@MisterMiyagi I'm hesitant to provide a Real Example because I worry that it'll become the focus of everything. But if it helps explain: I personally think it's ridiculous that apple.stackexchange.com is "Ask Different", a reference to a tagline that's been dead longer than some SE users have been alive. But it has strong support from active users who read meta. Now, I think ultimately I'm the odd one out here, so I just wrote a concurring answer on an old apple meta SE and made my peace with it. But supposing instead I really felt this was important, I'd be faced with this question.)

I think the example should be extreme for two reasons. 1) If it's anything other than a worst case scenario, the correct answer is "live with it." 2) people aren't usually entirely rational about how severe something is that slighted them, and so if somebody's ever thinking "I wish the broader SE network would step in and fix this" they're already thinking it's the worst case scenario. In most cases, it probably isn't (and I suspect any good answer to this post will include "in all likelihood you are in the wrong, and even if you're right, is it really worth getting upset over?").

@MisterMiyagi, it's not purely hypothetical.  It reads a lot like the early history of the site now known as "Software Engineering"

There are, to a more or less accurate portrayal, sites now on the network that match this description. They're allowed because the proposal involved making promises and either meeting them when scrutinised or well, not meeting them but being allowed to slide anyway, because ¡engagement! and/or KPI effects. They're  not going away, too many vested interests are already present. Just look at how hard it is to get rid of existing sites that nobody cares about, i.e. impossible, let alone sites that have human involvement and support. Your only option is get over it, don't visit.

I can definitely relate to feeling this way. And HNQ makes "getting over it" hard.

The site fades away.

@Kaia "somebody disagrees with a site and feels that they're right and obviously justified and everybody else is wrong" That is the internet in a nutshell.

If this is a purely hypothetical scenario, I feel discussing it is a waste of everyone's time, IMO. And if it's not hypothetical, not openly stating what site you're discussing also isn't useful.

"deal with it, don't visit that site" Sounds like perfect advice and almost self-answer to me. Maybe the question could motivate more why this shouldn't be the case, i.e. why more than personal avoidance is somehow good for the whole network. Why would I want to do more? Also the obvious alternative would be to open a question on meta there and if this doesn't help then here, wouldn't it?

What sort of person do you become if you stand for mod with the intention of going against the prevailing wind? Do you stick to your guns or allow yourself to be co-opted? I can't help but think that a certain amount of spinning the truth may be necessary.

A wise man once told me, "The bad drives out the good."

We've been down this road before. Literature.SE's first iteration was shut down because the site failed to thrive and was consequently thought unfit for Stack Exchange. Literature.SE's second iteration is vibrant today...

Community consensus is typically free to develop in such a way as it uses the platform as members deem fit. Of course there are limits, set by the Code of Conduct, Terms of Service, moderator agreement, other documents, good "common" sense, and the occasional need for proper adjudication; but these are more extreme provisions than the ones mentioned here. But if a community is committed to a scope/format that you view as an error... well. Provided it causes no material harm for their belief to be proven wrong, speak your mind and then let them decide. The outcome may surprise you.

But if there is a material harm, it needs to be elucidated and discussed clearly, openly, fairly, honestly. A good-faith effort to resolve it should be expected (but understanding that not all harms can be solved for). Communities here should not turn a blind eye to situations that impact the experience of others in their neighborhood. I say this because your post here mixes these two situations, one where you disagree with the community and the other where the community is causing harm. They are, in fact, separate, with different resolution pathways. It's important to keep that in mind.

The answer depends on the specific scenario, you have several different ones in your post that require different approaches.

Something about a site's behaviour is negatively impacting the "Hot Network Questions" sidebar tab or the experience of finding it in search results.

The HNQ are a network feature, so this is something that is not about the site alone and thereby entirely on-topic here on MSE. It is also valid to complain about this as it affects you on different sites. Now, whether this complaint will be well received or not depends entirely on why you're objecting to those HNQ questions. If you want to force your own narrow worldview onto everyone this might not go over well. But if some question titles are considered inappropriate by many this might be a reason to intervene. Usually this would either happen by simply talking to the mods there and letting them handle this by editing the problematic titles. Or by adding keywords to the blacklist that filters out such inappropriate titles.

A decision with majority support is unfairly negatively impacting a minority of users.

If the decision violates the Code of Conduct in your opinion it would be valid to directly contact SE. Posting here on MSE would also work, just consider if it is useful to draw much more attention to that particular mess, or if it would be unhelpful.

A decision with majority support violates SE network policy.

There is no such thing as SE network policies. There is the code of conduct (and the ToS, privacy policy, ...), but that's it in terms of actual network-wide rules. There are a lot more conventions that people sometimes call network policies. This was more of an issue in the old days when new sites were established and people discussed how to handle list questions, why meta tags are bad and similar topics. There is for example a network-wide consensus that meta tags are bad, but it is still not a network policy. At least one site knowingly breaks that rule, and that is completely within their right. Those are all more guidelines than law.
But if you mean "Code of Conduct" by SE network policy, see my answer to the point above.

I believe that a site should be deleted or changed in scope, or the site has decided to change its scope in a way I disagree with.

You can try to convince the community of that site by posting on their per-site meta. This probably won't go well in most cases unless you actually participate on that site and make a convincing argument. Your only chance in all other cases would be if the scope includes topics that somehow inherently violate the CoC.

You... don't go there?
At a personal level, if a space on the internet doesn't give you joy, perhaps its let it go. Its existence should never be, in a sense a personal affront. I don't think we're talking about that though.  Sometimes for minor annoyances - I guess sometimes its worth bringing it up, but you're generally in a place cause the benefits outweigh the
I somehow do not feel we're talking about that though. Perhaps we're talking about duty

XKCD 386
Your example does talk about deep, systemic issues in the hypothetical site. In theory the first line of defence against that would be the community and moderators, and where that fails. The second line of defence is - ideally, the community team would intervene, either indirectly (via meta) or my stepping in and assisting the moderation team
GenAI's an interesting case since it skipped the usual process, and is moderated by the community team. If things go wrong, I'd presume they'd know quite quickly.
I think its worth bringing up an old example of what happens when a site's going the wrong way in beta - I used to be a software recommendations moderator (then I took an arrow to the... no actually real life happened) and the site has a very unique scope, and requirements. We had a community team member let us know we were doing it all wrong.
Setting expectations and maintaining standards is an essential part of any site. Interestingly I've seen some of these things individually
I think the software recommendations and hardware recommendations sites are good examples of a topic traditionally seen as "The posts there are all subjective and unanswerable!" - on the other hand the expectations are designed to mitigate the worst of it.

The users have formed factions and are starting an eternal flamewar!

Have you seen meta on a bad day? An essential part of managing a community is about trying to resolve these disputes, metaphorically tossing the worst of the trouble makers out the metaphorical window, reassuring the innocent bystanders and so on. Where I moderate, and sometimes where I don't - I'd say using what influence and goodwill I have to try to resolve these things is quite satisfying

The mods aren't doing anything, or are encouraging breaking SE rules!

Ever thought of becoming a moderator there? More seriously - If mods are inactive - there's a chance they're burnt out, or have real life concerns that take precedence.
Actively breaking rules is more interesting - are they encouraging COC violations ? Is it a rule that might be counterproductive to the broader community good? Not everything SE does is wise.

The subject is stupid and unsuited for SE!

There's 200 over sites on SE. I don't go to Islam cause I'm not Muslim, Christianity cause I'm not Christian, Judaism cause I'm not a jew, and Hinduism because I'm actually Hindu (and I really don't need more religion in my life :D) . However people find value in these sites - and weirdly Q&A and religion seem to be a decent fit. Some people disagree with the existence of these sites at all. Sometimes, well, just cause it doesn't work for you doesn't mean it doesn't work for everyone else
The issue with gen AI isn't the subject - its that it skipped the A51 system and frankly, SE's actions with AI are a little tonedeaf considering community sentiments about it.

The comment section looks like a facebook wall! Stop wishing each other happy birthday!


That said, that should be on chat, and a gentle reminder of our somewhat neglected third space wouldn't be amiss.
Practically, if we have unhealthy sites, there has to be an intervention but it can't be one person doing it. That said, none of this is new or unprecedented. In a sense the system and community culture generally manages, but if there's major issues, there's nothing wrong with a polite meta post or escalation.

"Actively breaking rules is more interesting - are they encouraging COC violations ?" There are a lot of other things that could matter here. For example, a site could actively encourage OPs to post duplicates or answers to speculate on unclear questions or to address individual aspects of blatantly unfocused questions; more generally they could encourage use of the software as if it were discussion forum software.

As you laid this out, this is purely hypothetical and with all the guardrails in place, this is not at all a plausible scenario. Almost any new site proposal needs to go through Area 51 and would get voted down, if any of your claims were right. Even if they get past that, what you put forward will result in low participation, hence, not graduating. But for the sake of argument, let's entertain this.
Basically you're saying what if there was a community that wouldn't follow rules that are very reason SE networks work and are engaging in self-destructive actions. All we can do is not visiting that site. If anything spills over, for instance, moderators redirect users to other sites and they bring their unwanted behavior with them, we deal with those appropriately. If those issues become so frequent that handling them would have an adverse effect on other aspects of curation/moderation, then we can bring the specific cases to MSE. The difference then is that we won't be discussing a hypothetical situation without any specifics and we'd have a better grasp on what is the appropriate action.
Bottom line, for me, is that as long as the fire is not spreading, I am fine letting the users of particular site hanging out in their corner. They say it's fine, so it must be fine.


I think you have a very valid point, but the question is entirely moot. Nothing will be done, and SE will devolve into another 'failed attempt that at first glance sounded good'. It will go the way of Twitter, FaceBook, and any number of other once-popular sites. Even Google as a search engine is being supplanted, as people 'deal with it' by walking away.
The historical reality itself can not be made to 'go away'. The historical narrative is clear - when 'deal with it, don't visit that site' becomes the only enforcement technique for combating the proliferation of ignorance, there is and always will be a certain segment of humanity (the spreaders of ignorance) that will recognize 'absolute freedom is another word for tyranny'. Once they realize they will suffer absolutely no restrictions or resistance (so-called 'freedom of expression'), they will grow exponentially in strength, and start invading other sites. They will not 'go away', everyone else (decency) will end up 'going away', or giving up. That is the thing about 'democracy' - a concerted attack by a small well organized group can impose their tyranny on one small segment, by the attrition of reasoning individuals from that segment. To achieve democratic domination, they simply   convince the majority to 'leave them alone' in that segment, and they end up the only faction voting in that realm. One by one, the realms fall. Eventually, they control the majority of the realms, even though the majority of people are in opposition. Pandora's box has been opened, and becomes impossible to shut except through extreme authoritarian control.
Don't take it personally - it is not a concerted attack on you individually, it is a concerted attack on knowledge in general, and there will always be a segment of humanity that recognizes 'general ignorance is the source of their power'.
Consider what is happening in American education, if you doubt the truth of this reality. One by one, under the guise of 'personal freedom', ignorance takes over the various realms of education and schooling, by chasing enlightenment out of that realm through constant attrition, until there are no more public realms that promote enlightenment left, and there are no more 'authorities' left to combat the movement. All in the name of 'freedom of expression' and 'hesitancy to suppress ignorance', a general 'deal with it, don't visit that site' attitude.
Unfortunately, 'freedom of expression' and 'freedom from ignorance' are incompatible objectives. Under conditions of unconditional 'freedom of expression', history has always demonstrated that 'ignorance' will ultimately prevail. Ignorance does not 'go away' by ignoring it, it only goes away by actively engaging it and preventing its proliferation.
